# Determine value depending on input types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select type` dropdown, which upon selection redirects users to another page. I want them to be warned if they try to navigate away without saving when using this `select` dropdown.

However it needs to ignore this specific `select type` as one of the `input types` when determining that an input type has changed. This is my script, but it doesn't perform the desired action, (where `.send1` references to the actual `select type`):

```
 $(document).on('change', '.send1', function(){ 
     if($(":input").not('.send1')){
         $(":input").change(function(){
         unsaved = true;
        });
     }
  });
```

If `unsaved` ==  true then a users have a warning that there are unsaved changes.

Comment: try adding the prompt() function in order to prompt the user

Comment: Please don't use prompt.  If anything, write a custom modal.

Comment: actually hes right prompt gives an input box not exactly the most useful option but modal is only supported by chrome canary so it might be easier to merely make a popup with javascript activated with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.not()` method returns a jQuery object, and an object is considered a truthy value in JavaScript, you should use the `length` property for checking the length of the collection. But here this is not the main problem, the whole logic doesn't sound promising.  If you want to exclude an element from the selection you can use the `:not` in your selector:

```
var unsaved = false;

$(document).on('change', '.send1:not("select.specific")', function() {
      unsaved = true;
}); 

$('select.specific').on('change', function() {
   if (unsaved) {
      // show a modal/alert something...
   } else {
     // redirect
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks using `:not()` seems to have been the correct selector to have used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're asking.  It seems you're trying to determine if an input control has the class 'send1' - and if so, you ignore it?  Why are you binding all of your inputs to your event handler?  Can you post your HTML markup?

The closest I can come to helping is to recommend that you put a class on all of your inputs that COULD have unsaved data in them.  Then, write an event handler for your select list that redirects to another page:

```
$("#ddlThatRedirects").change(function(e){
     if (CheckFields()){
          //Put whatever alerting you want here
     }
     else{
          //Put redirect or postback logic here
     }
});

function CheckFields(){
     var UnsavedChanges = false;
     $(".ClassNameOfInputs").each(function(){
          if ($(this).val().length > 0)
               UnsavedChanges = true;
     });
     return UnsavedChanges;
}
```